# Vectorized R function to produce sets of histograms

Tags: r, function, plot, histogram

I have a vectorized R function (see below). At each run, the function plots two histograms. My goal is that when argument `n` is a vector (see example of use below), the function plots length of `n` separate sets of these histograms (ex: if `n` is a vector of length `2`, I expected two sets of histograms i.e., 4 individual histograms)?

I have tried the following with no success. Is there a way to do this?

```
t.sim = Vectorize(function(n, es, n.sim){

  d = numeric(n.sim)
  p = numeric(n.sim)

  for(i in 1:n.sim){
    N = sqrt((n^2)/(2*n))
    x = rnorm(n, es, 1)
    y = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    a = t.test(x, y, var.equal = TRUE)
    d[i] = a[[1]]/N
    p[i] = a[[3]]
  }
  par(mfcol = c(2, length(n)))
  hist(p) ; hist(d) 
}, "n")
# Example of use:
t.sim(n = c(30, 300), es = .1, n.sim = 1e3) # `n` is a vector of `2` so I expect 
                                            #  4 histograms in my graphical device
```

Comment: it's a vector but somehow the function runs the input twice so length n is 1 in each iteration, you can test it by printing length(n) inside the function and you also get two sets of plots instead of 1.

Comment: I think there is no simpler way to solve this than putting `par(mfrow = c(2, 2)` outside the function and removing it within the function. By changing it will always be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorize seems to be based on mapply, which would essentially call the function numerous times while cycle through your inputs vector. Hence, the easier way out probably just calls it outside the function

```
t.sim = Vectorize(function(n, es, n.sim){

  d = numeric(n.sim)
  p = numeric(n.sim)

  for(i in 1:n.sim){
    N = sqrt((n^2)/(2*n))
    x = rnorm(n, es, 1)
    y = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    a = t.test(x, y, var.equal = TRUE)
    d[i] = a[[1]]/N
    p[i] = a[[3]]
  }
  # par(mfcol = c(2, npar))
  hist(p) ; hist(d) 
}, "n")

#inputs    
data <- c(30,300)
par(mfcol = c(2, length(data)))

t.sim(n = data, es = c(.1), n.sim = 1e3)
```